# How do I turn an inequality involving only |a| and |b| into an inequality involving |b + a| and |b - a|?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I'm working on a proof which involves showing that if $|a| < 2|b|$, then either $|b + a| < |b|$ or $|b - a| < |b|$. I've tried using contradiction (assuming that both $|b + a|,|b - a| \geq |b|$ and then various techniques (in particular, the reverse triangle inequality), but I've had no luck on this; most of my arguments just end up showing that an absolute value is nonnegative. Could anyone give a hint as to the direction I should be pursuing?

Comment: Is this statement true? Consider a=0,b=1.

Comment: @JY1853 , I think he forgot to add that condition : $a,b \neq 0,1$.

Comment: It's possible that we actually need $|b + a| \leq |b|$ or $|b - a| \leq |b|$; the question was worded as "either $b + a$ or $b - a$ is less than $b$ in absolute value", so it's kind of ambiguous.

Comment: @Isomorphism, I think they (the makers of the question)  only intended to put $b$ inside the absolute value function.

Comment: @Spectre, so you mean they might want $a + b \leq |b|$? I also just want to note that we can have $a,b = 0,1$, because these are actually entries in a matrix in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @Isomorphism : I know nothing about matrices, but I feel that my perception was correct, because if it was like both the sides were in the absolute value function, $a,b = 0,1$ would become a counterexample.

Comment: @Spectre Sorry, I changed the question to reflect that possibility; it was stated in words, so it was a bit ambiguous, so I now believe the question was intended to mean "$|b + a| \leq |b|$ or $|b - a| \leq |b|$"; this would resolve the counterexample, but I'm not sure it necessarily helps with finding the proof. I'm looking at it now.

Comment: Supposing its a+b<|b| or the other case, try squaring both sides of the original equation, and see where (2b+a)(2b-a)>0 leads you.

Comment: @Isomorphism , now all's clear.

Comment: Sometimes you need to split inequalities into alternatives for this sort of proof, e.g., expanding "$|x|<|y|$" into "$x<|y|$ or $-x<|y|$". This can lead to multiple levels of expansion, but you can generally merge alternatives at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following:

If
$$sign(a) = sign(b)$$
then:
$$|a| + |b| = |a + b|$$
otherwise:
$$|a| + |b| = |a - b|$$

Comment: Good +1.  Equivalently using triangle inequality, 
$\max(|a+b|, |a-b|) = \frac12\left(|a+b|+|a-b| \right)< \frac12\left( |a|+|b|+|a|+|b|\right)=|a|+|b|< 3|b|$
 as equality is not possible for non-zero $a, b$.